# Why do I keep getting this error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:" when running packages like pynput and keyboard on replit?

Tags: python, replit

I am trying to make a game with python on Replit and it will not run certain packages that I have already pip installed.

This is the code I ran:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("pressed p")
        break

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        print("pressed q")
        break
        
keyboard.on_press_key("r", lambda _:print("pressed r"))
```

Comment: repl.it is running your code _somewhere in the cloud_, on a machine that most likely doesn't have a keyboard. You are writing the code on your browser, but it's running on some machine somewhere. Have you tried running your code _locally_?

Comment: No, I have not. Do you have any resources or tools explaining how to do that?

Comment: You can't use replit for this, maybe try using Notepad++ for windows or similar alternatives if you have another OS? VIM works for linux and Atom Text Editor for Mac. Personally, I like to use PyCharm because it just provides one (if not the) best IDE's out there. All the options above are free (PyCharm CE is free) and allow you to use a local python interpreter, in which you can install modules via `pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in repl.it sadly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).